# conda environment with wrong java version

Tags: java, java-8, conda

I created a new conda environment with the command `conda create --name condaenv python=2.7 openjdk=8`. When I activate this environment using `conda activate condaenv` and check the java version, however, I get:

```
openjdk version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 7.12.0.3-linux64) (build 1.7.0_91-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 7.12.0.3-linux64) (build 24.91-b15, mixed mode)
```

How can I get the correct java version for this conda environment?

I checked that the `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable is correct, and it is since running `echo $JAVA_HOME` gives `/home/ag956/.conda/envs/condaenv`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by first installing Java 1.8 with the command:

```
conda install -c main java-1.8.0-openjdk-cos7-s390x
```

And then creating the environment.